# Issue when parsing JSON with NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, parsing

I'm reading a JSON file and parsing it with NodeJS, the JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "x": 9.996,
    "y": 0.135,
    "v": {
        "x1": 0.653,
        "y1": -0.064
    },
    "z": 1.4730991609821347
}, {
    ...
}
```

So I can easily put that into a variable, `JSON.parse()` it and access it without any problems:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(jsonVar)
console.log(parsed.id) // prints 5
```

The problem comes when I try to access `x1` or `y1` from `parsed.v`. It comes out with an object and it behaves really weird.

I have tried:

```
 parsed.v.x1 // gave me an error, x1 doesn't exist
```

also

```
 var string = JSON.stringify(parsed.v) // returns {"x":0.653,"y":-0.064}
```

Trying to parse the above and access it also gives me an error

```
var parsedNew = JSON.parse(string)
console.log(parsedNew.x) //error
```

Am I missing something there? Running out of ideas really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is no need to parse or do anything to access the data, as it ***already is a javascript object***, try something like this:

```
var json = {
    "id": 5,
    "x": 9.996,
    "y": 0.135,
    "v": {
        "x1": 0.653,
        "y1": -0.064
    },
    "z": 1.4730991609821347
};

console.log(json.v.x1); // this will output '0.653'
```

And by the way, `JSON.stringify()` just converts the input into a `String`, so it is not really what you need.

Hope this helps!